# How to importrange and filter between two lines of text

Tags: filter, google-sheets, importrange

I am trying to importrange specific text from a column, so for example I want the filter between cell A2 "Name" and Cell A9 "Rye". That way if I add a row, it will automatically update. 
The point is to break down the column A into Multiple Column by category (Whiskey, Rye, Gin, Tequila)
That way I can make a dynamic drop down that pulls everything from the columns.

Thanks everyone!

[image: Workbook]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/11tl8xzJnxei94FLcL2Y8z6VsAEzzzu1MzSrjlThYt6k/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=109306486275879772395

Comment: So "Spirits" tab would stay the same. "Sheet 1" is the sheet I was trying to filter into multiple columns based on category (Whiskey, Rum, Rye, ect."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**paste this in A1 cell and drag it to the right**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(JOIN(CHAR(10), IF(
 IMPORTRANGE("1MTk7LIxsbUDvQWQ2ABjuk60oCOPdCOytmJ1MxJdtE9s", 
             "'Liquor Master Pricing'!A2:A"&COUNTA(
 IMPORTRANGE("1MTk7LIxsbUDvQWQ2ABjuk60oCOPdCOytmJ1MxJdtE9s",
             "'Liquor Master Pricing'!A2:A"))+COUNTIF(IF(
 IMPORTRANGE("1MTk7LIxsbUDvQWQ2ABjuk60oCOPdCOytmJ1MxJdtE9s", 
             "'Liquor Master Pricing'!A2:A"&COUNTA(
 IMPORTRANGE("1MTk7LIxsbUDvQWQ2ABjuk60oCOPdCOytmJ1MxJdtE9s",
             "'Liquor Master Pricing'!A2:A")))<>"",
 IMPORTRANGE("1MTk7LIxsbUDvQWQ2ABjuk60oCOPdCOytmJ1MxJdtE9s",
             "'Liquor Master Pricing'!A2:A"), "♥"), "♥"))<>"",
 IMPORTRANGE("1MTk7LIxsbUDvQWQ2ABjuk60oCOPdCOytmJ1MxJdtE9s",
             "'Liquor Master Pricing'!A2:A"), "♥")), "♥"), , COLUMN()), CHAR(10))), ))
```

[image]

**note: using `IMPORTRANGE` can get very slow. to speed up things its recommended to import data `=IMPORTRANGE("1MTk7LIxsbUDvQWQ2ABjuk60oCOPdCOytmJ1MxJdtE9s", "'Liquor Master Pricing'!A2:A")` on a separate sheet and then reference ranges from there for this formula**

Comment: Way to go! All hail the Google Sheets Guru!